# What happens if send low value swift payment via BEN?

Tags: money-transfer, fees, international-transfer, swift

I am wondering what happens if I made a low value swift payment (e.g under £10) which is less than the transaction fee. Would the payment be rejected?

Comment: It should be like buying something online where the postage exceeds the cost of the item - high postage shouldn’t automatically block the purchase. The bank still gets their fee and you might have a legitimate reason for making that low-value payment, so I don’t see why they would reject it. But check with your bank - they should be able to give you a definitive answer.